# How to have conditional design attributes for different interfaces in aura components?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, sfdc, aura-framework

I want my aura to be exposed on both flowscreen and lightning record page. I have implemented the interfaces.

But I want different design attributes to be visible when I configure it for record page vs flows.